# Extract groups within parenthesis when there is an optional substring delimiter

Tags: python, regex, string, unicode, delimiter

Given the 2 strings:

```
l = ['作主 (zuòzhǔ)', '座右铭 (座右銘, zuòyòumíng)']
```

The desired output is:

```
('作主', None, 'zuòzhǔ')
('作主', '座右銘', 'zuòyòumíng')
```

Ive tried to extract the groups as such, but I'm unable to split the `座右銘, 'zuòyòumíng` into 2 groups:

```
l = ['作主 (zuòzhǔ)', '座右铭 (座右銘, zuòyòumíng)']
word = re.search(r'(.*)\s\((.*?)\)', l[0])

sim = word.group(1)
try:
    pinyin = word.group(3)
    trad = word.group(2)
except:
    pinyin = word.group(2)
    trad = None

print (sim, trad, pinyin)
```

I could do this:

```
try:
    pinyin = word.group(3)
    trad = word.group(2)
except:
    trad, pinyin = word.group(2).split(', ')
```

**But can the comma split be done within the regex?**

I've also tried this but it still capture the whole string within the `.*?`:

```
(.*)\s\((.*?[,][\s].*?)\)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the following regex:

```
(.*?) \((?:(.*?), )?(.*?)\)
```

The only difference is the  optional non-capturing group containing the part before the comma: `(?:(.*?), )?`.

```
In [4]: re.search(r'(.*?) \((?:(.*?), )?(.*?)\)', '座右铭 (座右銘, zuòyòumíng)').groups()
Out[4]: ('座右铭', '座右銘', 'zuòyòumíng')

In [5]: re.search(r'(.*?) \((?:(.*?), )?(.*?)\)', '作主 (zuòzhǔ)').groups()
Out[5]: ('作主', None, 'zuòzhǔ')
```